# What does it mean for the empty set to be connected and totally disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, terminology, connectedness

I am trying to prove that the empty set is disconnected, but every single post I can find on this topic is about showing empty set is connected.

Recall definition of connected. A set $S$ is connected if the set is not the disjoint union of proper clopen subsets $A \sqcup B$.

Then $\varnothing$ is by definition connected, since $\varnothing$ is clopen and $S = \varnothing$ is again clopen. So the only clopen sets of $S = \varnothing$ are $S$ and $\varnothing$ and neither are proper.

But there are also some posts telling me that the empty set is totally disconnected. Like Here: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=19492 or here [Is the Empty set an orientable manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222061/is-the-empty-set-an-orientable-manifold)

Can someone please elaborate what it means for the empty set is totally disconnected and does that imply that the empty set is disconnected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall the definitions:

> A space is **connected** if it cannot be written as union of two non-empty disjoint open subsets.
>
> A space is **disconnected** if it is not connected.
>
> A space is **totally disconnected** if it has no non-trivial connected subsets.

What about the empty space? It is connected, in fact vacuously so as it lacks non-empty subsets in the first place. Consequently it is not disconnected. On the other hand it is totally disconnected as its only subsets are (connected but) trivial.