# 'flimsy' spaces: removing any $n$ points results in disconnectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Consider the following property:

$\mathbb R$ is a connected space, but $\mathbb R\setminus \{p\}$ is disconnected for every $p\in \mathbb R$.

$S^1$ is a connected space and if we remove any point, it is still connected. But if we remove two arbitrary points $p$ and $q$, the resulting $S^1 \setminus \{p,q\}$ is disconnected.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let's call $X$ to be **$n$-flimsy** if removing fewer then $n$ arbitrary points leaves the space connected and removing any $n$ arbitrary (distinct) points disconnects the space.

We saw that $\mathbb R$ is $1$-flimsy and $S^1$ is $2$-flimsy (as $S^1 \setminus \{*\} \cong \mathbb R$).

**Question:** Is there a $3$-flimsy space?

So I'm searching for a space $X$ such that the removal of any $3$ points disconnects the space, but fewer don't.

I suspect that there is no such space. I thought  I could show it by showing first, that $1$- or $2$-flimsy spaces are in some way unique, but I found many examples of $1$-flimsy spaces which are significantly different (the long line, a variant of the topological sinus, trees).

Alternatively: Is there a standard terminology for this property? (it definitely 'feels' like $n$-connectivity in graph theory)

**Addendum 1:** A space $X=\{x,y\}$ with two points is a trivial $3$-flimsy example, since we cannot remove three distinct points. Of course, I'm interested in real examples.

**Addendum 2:** Since Qiaochu Yuan and Paul Frost argued that CW-complexes won't work, here are some thoughts concerning the finite case:

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space with finite $X$. Then $T$ is automatically an [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) and therefore has the *Specialization preorder* $\prec$. 
If we have a connected component $Z(x)$ of a point $x$ in a finite space with Alexandrov topology, then $Z(x)$ and its complement are closed and open, so they are downwardly closed. If we visualize $(X,T)$ by the graph $G$ which has $X$ as vertices and two vertices $v,w$ are connected if $v\prec w$ or $w \prec v$, then connected components in $T$ refer to connected components of the graph.  Deleting a point in $X$ corresponds to deleting the respective vertex.

*Claim*: There is no finite $1$-flimsy space (disregarding the trivial examples above). Otherwise we have a graph where the removal of any vertex results in a disconnected graph. This graph can't be finite.

*Corollary*: There are no finite $n$-flimy spaces for $n\in \mathbb N$ (disregarding the trivial examples above). The removal of one point results in a finite $n-1$-flimsy space, which can't exist (induction).

**Still open**: Are there nontrivial $3$-flimsy spaces? Those should be infinite and shouldn't be homeomorphic to CW-complexes.

**Addendum 3:** *Funfact*: Every topological space can be embedded into a $1$-flimsy space. Just add a real line to each point (as a one-point union). Alternatively, add $1$-spheres to every point. Then add $1$-spheres to each new point. Continue like this for eternity.

**Addendum 4:** In the setting of Whyburn's book *Analytic topology* it is shown, that a compact set cannot be $1$-flimsy (Chapter 3, Theorem 6.1). Since all my examples for $1$-flimsy spaces are non-compact: Is there an example of a compact $1$-flimsy space? Are all $n$-flimsy spaces non-compact (at least they are infinite)?

Comment: This is very similar to the concept of $n$ vertex connected in graph theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, it definitely feels like it (as I just edited) and the standard $n=1,2$ examples are graphs, but for $n=3$ it seems to be much harder.

Comment: You are looking for a space so that $X \setminus \{p,q\}$ is always connected, but for every triple of points $S$, $X \setminus S$ is disconnected?

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @Lorenzo: "Not 2-flimsy" doesn't necessarily mean $X\setminus\{p,q\}$ is always connected, just that there exists a pair $(p,q)$ for which it is connected (i.e., not always disconnected). In other words, your condition is stronger, I think.

Comment: @MPW you are right. I changed my definition accordingly.

Comment: Hmm. With the original definition, $[0,1]$ is 3-flimsy, but with the new definition it is not $k$-flimsy for any $k$ (since you now require removing *any* $k-1$ set of points to leave a connected remainder).

Comment: I think any "reasonable" 1-flimsy space (e.g. a CW complex) must be a tree, and I think you can use this to show that there aren't any "reasonable" 3-flimsy spaces.

Comment: Topological manifolds (with or without boundary) are not $3$-flimsy. As  Qiaochu Yuan remarked, CW-complexes are not $3$-flimsy: CW-complexes of dimension $> 1$ are not because you can remove $3$ points of any open cell of dimension $> 1$ without disconnecting the space, and $1$-dimensional CW-complexes are not because removing two points from an open $1$-cell disconnects the space. Have you tried finite spaces with non-discrete topology?

Comment: @PaulFrost, thanks for your comment. So CW-complexes are out. I thought about finite sets and added those thoughts to the question. Maybe I'll extend it later.

Comment: I've posed the question to a Facebook group for recreational mathematics. There have been no good leads yet. I've also had trouble finding a good approach to disproving the existence of 3-flimsy spaces that wouldn't also disprove the existence of 2-flimsy spaces (obviously, such an approach can't be valid).

Comment: "Otherwise we have a graph where the removal of one vertex results in a disconnected graph. This graph can't be finite." Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this isn't correct... e.g. take a path graph, or any graph with a bridge.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, my wording should be:"the removal of *any* vertex disconnects..." Then there can't be any leaves. I edited this part, thanks.

Comment: If you stay in the class of separable metrizable spaces then there are no n-flimsy sets for $n\ge 3$. Let me know if you want to see a proof. I do not currently have this book, but the problem might be discussed in Whyburn's "Analytic Topology".

Comment: @MoisheCohen I got the book, but it didn't help me very much. Neither did I find helpful clues to show something for $1$-flimsys nor did I really understand Whyburn's definition of topological space. Thanks for the hint anyway.\\\ I would be really happy to see a proof that $n$-flimsy spaces are not separable and metrizable at the same time, if you are able to provide it.

Comment: A little remark: If you take as your topological space a 3-fold point (think of an analogue of the real line with two origins but here you take a 3-fold origin and forget about the real line). This needs some careful definition but I think it can be done. Removing any two points is fine, removing three points results in the empty set which is as well connected as also disconnected. This gives an example of an $n$-flimsy space for all $n$. Anyway, I think this is a pathology and not what you are searching for, right?

Comment: @James If I understand right, your example is a set $X$ consisting of $3$ points together with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$? I'd call that a pathology in any case, whether I'd call $\emptyset$ connected or not, which is a pathology in its own.

Comment: @Babelfish Yes, that is one possible topology on this space (maybe there are others but I didn't check). What I wanted to point at is that it is not clear to me, how "pathological" an example can be. Should we stick to Euclidean topology? Topologies that are Hausdorff? At which point is an example too pathological. For example, I find my example much less pathological than the one mentioned in the first addendum by the OP.

Comment: @James If $\emptyset$ is disconnected, then your space is a $3$-flimsy example. If $\emptyset$ is connected, then $2$ points are a $3$-flimsy example.///In addendum 2, I showed that there are no "real" finite $3$-flimsy spaces. Apart from examples with $\leq 3$ points, every example of a $3$-flimsy space is welcome, hausdorff or not. If you can show that there are no $1,2$ or $3$-flimsy spaces what so ever, that's great. If you show it while assuming Hausdorff or compactness or metrizability or separability, that's still great.

Comment: @Babelfish OK, thanks. I will keep on thinking about your problem! Concerning connectedness of the empty set, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1630978/526015 -- Probably if we put another topology on the consisting of three points, this could give a satisfying example?

Comment: @James Let $X$ be any space with $3$ points. Then removing any $3$ distinct points results in the emptyset $\emptyset$ which, according to your link, is connected. Therefore $X$ is not $3$-flimsy, as $X\setminus \{a,b,c\}$ should be disconnected.

Comment: @Babelfish Your definition says that the result from removing three points should be disconnected. Since the empty set is as well connected as also disconnected, it provides an example.

Comment: @James, according to your link, the empty set is **not** disconnected (as it is connected), but rather *totally disconnected*. So it does not provide an example.

Comment: @Babelfish I was assuming that totally disconnected implies disconnected but this is wrong (of course!). Sorry for that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I did not make any mistake, 3-flimsy spaces does not exist. You can check [this link](http://lebarde.alwaysdata.net/fadelian/three-flimsy.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0GE-TiJUWfhXF4dmntbyRwYREdSS6U3D3D8iLOCYVw02YcLt_ERjmfUUc) for my proof and some other results about 2-flimsy spaces. Without giving all the details, here are the big steps of the proof:

First, we show that if $X$ is a 2-flimsy space and $x\neq y\in X$, then $X\backslash\{x,y\}$ has exactly two connected components. For this, we consider 3 open sets $U_1,U_2,U_3$ such that $(U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3)\cap\{x,y\}^{c}=X\backslash\{x,y\}$, $U_1\cap U_2\cap\{x,y\}^{c}=U_1\cap U_3\cap\{x,y\}^{c}=U_2\cap U_3\cap\{x,y\}^{c}=\emptyset$, and $\forall i\in\{1,2,3\},\ U_i\cap\{x,y\}^{c}\neq\emptyset$. If $u_1\in U_1\cap\{x,y\}^{c}$ and $u_2\in U_2\cap\{x,y\}^{c}$, then we can show $X\backslash\{u_1,u_2\}$ is connected.

The second big step is to consider $x,t,s\in X$, three distinct points of a $2$-flimsy space. We denote $C_1(t),C_2(t)$ the two connected components of $X\backslash\{x,t\}$ and $C_1(s),C_2(s)$ the two connected components of $X\backslash\{x,s\}$. We suppose $s\in C_1(t)$ and $t\in C_1(s)$. Then $D=C_1(t)\cap C_1(s)$ is one of the two connected components of $X\backslash\{t,s\}$. In fact, the finite number of connected components implies $C_2(t)\cup\{x\}$ is connected, so the same goes for $(C_2(t)\cup\{x\})\cup(C_2(s)\cup\{x\})$ : the only thing to verify is the connectedness of $D$. The proof looks like to the first step. If $U,V$ are two open sets of $X$ such that $U\cap V\cap D=\emptyset$, $(U\cup V)\cap D=D$, and $U\cap D\neq\emptyset$ and $V\cap D\neq\emptyset$, and if $u\in U\cap D$ and $v\in V\cap D$, then we show $X\backslash\{u\}$ or $X\backslash\{v\}$ is not connected.

Finally, if $X$ is a $3$-flimsy space and $x,y,t,s$ some distinct points of $X$, then $D$ (defined as previously in $X\backslash\{y\}$, a 2-flimsy space) is open and closed in $X\backslash\{x,t,s\}$ and in $X\backslash\{y,t,s\}$, so it is open and closed in $X\backslash\{t,s\}$, which is not connected. So $X$ is not a 3-flimsy space after all.

Comment: Hello Robin Khanfir, I finally got the time to parse your proof. It is not easy to read, but I think the proof is sound. Thank you very much for your efforts! I'm sorry it took me so long to proof-read.\\\ two minor typos: In the proof of Lemma 1, it should be $\tilde{U} \cup \tilde{V} \subset X \setminus \{u,v\}$ instead of $\tilde{U} \cap \tilde{V} \subset X \setminus \{u,v\}$. In Theorem 1, you write $U_2 \cap U_2$, which should be $U_2 \cap U_3$ instead.\\\...

Comment: I didn't quite get you argumentation in Theorem 1, when you write "either open in $X\setminus\{y\}$ and $X\setminus \{z\}$ or closed in $X\setminus \{y\}$ and $X \setminus\{z\}$, because $X\setminus\{y\}$ and $X \setminus\{z\}$ are n-flimsy". Though I checked the correctness myself, so it should be fine anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proposition that I believe will help to at least figure out whether or not a $3$-path-flimsy space exists.
An $n$-path-flimsy space would be a space such that removing fewer than $n$ points would keep the space path-connected, but removing any $n$ points would make the space not path-connected.

**Proposition A:** Let $X$ be a $2$-path-flimsy space and $x\in X$.
Then for any path-connected open neighborhood $N$ of $x$, such that $X\setminus N$ is also path-connected, the space $N\setminus\{x\}$ has at most two path-connected components.

*Proof of Proposition A:* The proof is by contradiction.
Assume for the contrary that there exists $x\in X$ with a path-connected open neighborhood $N$, such that $X\setminus N$ is also path-connected, and such that the space $N\setminus\{x\}$ has three distinct path-connected components $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$.
Let $c_i\in C_i$.
Since $X$ is $2$-path-flimsy, the space $X\setminus\{x\}$ is path-connected, so $N\neq X$, so we can find $p\in X\setminus N$.

Fix some $1\leq i\leq3$.
Since $N$ is path-connected, it follows that the set $C_i\cup\{x\}$ is path-connected.
This is because there is a path from $x$ to $c_i$ in $N$, and we can deduce that the last moment the path was not in $C_i$, it must have been at $x$ by the definition of path-connected component.
By similar reasoning, we find that $C_i\cup(X\setminus N)$ is path-connected.

Since $C_i$ is a path-connected component of $N\setminus\{x\}$, any path that leaves $C_i$ must pass through $X\setminus(N\setminus\{x\})=\{x\}\cup(X\setminus N)$ first.
Since $X$ is $2$-path-flimsy, $X\setminus\{c_i\}$ is path-connected, so from any $c\in C_i$ there is a path that leaves $C_i$.
We can conclude that there is either a path from $c$ to $x$ in $C_i\cup\{x\}$, or there is a path from $c$ to $p$ in $C_i\cup(X\setminus N)$.

We can now conclude that $X\setminus\{c_1,c_2\}$ is path-connected, which contradicts the fact that $X$ is $2$-path-flimsy and finishes the proof of Proposition A.
This is because every point is either path-connected to $x$ or $p$ and $c_3$ is path-connected to both.

Comment: Somehow $n$-path-flimsy seems to be a feature that is easier to grasp than $n$-flimsy. In particular, some examples for $1$- or $2$-flimsy spaces are not $1$- or $2$-path-flimsy, like the sinus of the topologist./// Your proof is nice, I think I got it. And I think I see how your proof might show that there are no hausdorff $3$-path-flimsy spaces. Nice!