# More on flimsy spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've recently encountered this [very nice question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939445/flimsy-spaces-removing-any-n-points-results-in-disconnectedness) on flimsy spaces and have come up with the following generalised version of the question, one which isn't also answered (in an obvious fashion) by one of the answers posted there:

**Definition:** Let $n$ and $k$ be two non-negative integers. A $k$-connected topological space is called *$(n,k)$-flimsy* if the space, obtained from $X$ by removing any choice of $n-1$ distinct points inside $X$, is $k$-conntected, and the space, obtained from $X$ by removing any choice of $n$ distinct points, is not $k$-connected.

It is evident from the definition that there always exists $(1,k)$ and $(2,k)$-flimsy spaces for each $k \in \mathbb N_{0}$ (Take $\mathbb R^{k+1}$ and $S^{k+1}$). One could probably also come up with more exotic (non-CW) examples.

**Question: Is it true that no $(3,k)$-flimsy space exists ?**

The original question is concerned with the case $k = 0$. I don't see how the point-set theoretical methods employed in the proof can be extended to higher $k$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $M$ is a noncompact manifold, then $M \setminus \{pt\} \simeq M \vee S^{\dim M - 1}$.  

In particular, if $M$ is any manifold, then $\pi_k(M \setminus \{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n\}) = \pi_k(M \setminus\{p_1\}) \oplus (\pi_k(S^{\dim M - 1}))^{n-1}.$ In particular, if a manifold minus $n$ points fails to be $k$-connected, the same is true for the manifold minus two points. So there are no $(n,k)$-flimsy manifolds for $n > 2$, and a $(2,k)$-flimsy manifold must be compact.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the homotopy equivalence of your first sentence ? I have to admit that I don't quite see it.

Comment: The picture is: Triangulate M. It is known (and easy to see when M is the interior of a compact manifold) that M deformation retracts onto a subcomplex of 1 dimension less. The thing to do is to argue that you can also deformation retract onto something of the form $M' \cup \sigma$, where $M'$ is that subcomplex and $\sigma$ is a simplex which may be collapsed onto its boundary faces; one may argue this is homotopy equivalent relative to $\sigma$ to $M' \vee \sigma$. Now, puncturing inside $\sigma$ leaves you with an extra sphere.